# Java stopped working, javaw.exe at 100% CPU

Tags: java

Windows XP 32bit. Working fine for a long time.

Recently, everything related to Java stopped working. Even the Java app in the Control Panel is not working anymore.

Whenever anything Java-related is launched, apparently nothing happens, no application appears to launch at all, except CPU usage goes to 100%. Investigating it, it turns out the javaw.exe process is at 100% CPU. And it stays like that forever.

I tried reinstalling Java, disabled the anti-virus, etc. Tried JavaRa (a tool to clean up old Java files) - nothing helped.

I can run "java -version" in the Command Prompt, and that one works fine, but it's no consolation.

I'm stumped.

Comment: What does that java -version say by the way.  Also consider using sysinternals procexp to find out about the dlls that are used and whether they really belong to the newly installed JRE/JDK.

Comment: Try logging in and running Java apps under a different user account. If it works, there's probably a file corruption issue associated with your user profile.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of VirtualBox.

This is a virtual machine running on VirtualBox. The latest VBox update broke Java. I filed a [bug report](http://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8794) and posted a [warning](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=41058) on their forum.

They really need to get their act together. :(

Comment: It's great that you have answered this question yourself, but you should also accept the answer - click the tick mark to the left.